# Constuct name for assigning C functions like .pr_input = sctp_input

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

Can someone tell me the name for assigning functions like this in C -

```
.pr_type =              SOCK_SEQPACKET,
.pr_domain =            &inetdomain,
.pr_protocol =          IPPROTO_SCTP,
.pr_flags =             PR_WANTRCVD,
.pr_input =             sctp_input,
.pr_ctlinput =          sctp_ctlinput,
.pr_ctloutput =         sctp_ctloutput,
.pr_init =              sctp_init,
```

I can't seem to get the right search string for googling it.

Comment: I suppose this is within the initialization of a structure? `.` *identifier* is a designator, the whole thing happens within initialization, see e.g. [designated initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) The right hand side are function pointers.

Comment: I was just looking for the name. So it is "Designated Initializers". Thanks a lot.